# Как получить Wildcard-SSL-сертификат Lets-Encrypt в VestaCP?

Tags: ssl, vesta, wildcards

Ubuntu 16.04 + панель управления сайтами VestaCP.

Куплен домен site.ru, для которого на стороне регистратора задан IP-адрес в значении А-записей для site.ru и *.site.ru.

Задача c помощью панели VestaCP получить автоматически обновляемый wildcard SSL-сертификат Lets Encrypt для домена site.ru и его поддоменов *.site.ru. Т.е. один общий SSL-сертификат для домена и всех его поддоменов.

Как это сделать - непонятно. Если кому удавалось это осуществить, просьба расписать по шагам что и как делать.

Прошу расписать как это сделать именно при помощи панели VestaCP, а не кучей инструкций в командной строке в ручном режиме. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В этом видео хорошо показывается как настроить службу DNS для получения WildCard сертификата: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trMhdlQlLyI

Дополнительно в панели VestaCP прописываем:

1) для сайта алиас *.site.ru

2) в настройках DNS А-запись со звездочкой и IP-сервера

В настройках регистратора домена дополнительно прописываем А-запись со звездочкой (вместо поддоменов) и IP-адресом сервера в качестве значения.

И WildCard SSL-сертификат Lets Encrypt получаем без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Если DNS записи редактируются на стороне регистратора, то никак.

> Получение wildcard сертификата сейчас возможно только через DNS challenge, где необходимо временно создать TXT запись вида _acme-challenge.example.com с определенным значением.

Либо думать по интеграции VestaCP и api регистратора, или управлять записями средствами VestaCP (но здесь много нюансов).

Comment: В VestaCP есть раздел DNS. Но как его настраивать под wildcard, что прописывать - непонятно.

Comment: Вот это видео мне очень помогло решить проблему, всем спасибо:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trMhdlQlLyI . Только надо в настройках сайта прописать алиас   *.site.ru и соответственно А-запись со звездочкой в настройках DNS панели VestaCP